# The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField

Tags: mysql, django

I have a model:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    INACTIVE = 0
    ACTIVE = 1
    ARCHIVE = 2

    STATUS = (
        (INACTIVE, "Inactive"),
        (ACTIVE, "Active"),
        (ARCHIVE, "Archive"),
    )

    AIR_TOUR = 0
    GROUND_TOUR = 1
    SEA_TOUR = 2

    T_TYPES = (
        (AIR_TOUR, "Air_tour"),
        (GROUND_TOUR, "Ground_tour"),
        (SEA_TOUR, "Sea_tour"),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tour_from = models.ForeignKey(Airport, related_name='from_location')
    tour_to = models.ForeignKey(Airport, related_name='to_location')
    duration_day = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, null=True)
    duration_night = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True, null=True)
    transport_type = models.IntegerField(default=AIR_TOUR, choices=T_TYPES, blank=True, null=True)
    documents = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
    services = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='')

    airline = models.ForeignKey(Airline, null=True, blank=True)
    train = models.ForeignKey(Train, null=True, blank=True)
    bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, null=True, blank=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=INACTIVE, choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(default='2000-10-10')
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(default='2000-10-10')
```

I try to change status to `ARCHIVE` by this code:

```
test = Tour.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
test.status = ARCHIVE
test.save()
```

and get this error:

> The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.

`status` field is not `AutoField`. Why this error happend?

## UPDATE:

full stack trace:

```
  Django version 1.11, using settings 'project.settings_local'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8888/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /dashboard/tour/delete/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/py/project/dashboard/views_tour.py", line 196, in post
    tour.save()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 836, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 903, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 953, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 661, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1191, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 863, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1157, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 963, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 766, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 955, in get_db_prep_value
    value = connection.ops.validate_autopk_value(value)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py", line 155, in validate_autopk_value
    raise ValueError('The database backend does not accept 0 as a '
ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.
Internal Server Error: /dashboard/tour/delete/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/py/project/dashboard/views_tour.py", line 196, in post
    tour.save()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 836, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 903, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 953, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 661, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1191, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 863, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1157, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 963, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 766, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 955, in get_db_prep_value
    value = connection.ops.validate_autopk_value(value)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/operations.py", line 155, in validate_autopk_value
    raise ValueError('The database backend does not accept 0 as a '
ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.
```

Comment: There is no `status` model field defined. How do you assign `test.status`?

Comment: @nik_m sorry dude, I update question.

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace? And show us more of your view? As you say, it's not `test.field_15` causing the error, so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks, dude. I update the question and add the real name of fields and the full stack trace.

Comment: does it also happen if you do `test.save(update_fields=['status'])`?

Comment: @dirkgroten Yesssssssss, this worked. thanks. Please send this as an answer to I accept. Thank you very much.

Comment: but that's not an answer, it's a workaround (or better, trying to figure out what's going on). I don't have a clue why just saving wouldn't work. it's going to cause you more trouble down the line. what you should do is add your fields of the model one by one (`test.save(update_fields=['status', 'tour_from'])`, etc...) until you find the culprit.

Comment: or look in your database directly using SQL. Maybe something corrupt there. If it's just your dev database, no problem. delete the row and start again.

Comment: I'm having this issue, too. I scraped the database clean and reinitialized it with makemigrations and migrate. I'm using the admin interface to add a new record to an empty table (all of this project's tables are empty), and this table has no foreign keys.
What I'm seeing is that this seems to be failing when it logs the change.

Answer (score 2):

You likely have a foreign key field that contains a 0 (instead of null, or a valid value). If you don't have the proper foreign key constraints at the DB level (or you turned off foreign key checks when you added the constraints), there is nothing preventing invalid foreign key references from existing in that row.

Check the data in the all your foreign key fields for a 0: `tour_from`, `tour_to`, 
`airline`, `train`, `bus`, `user`, `creator`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work. Since the object is already in the database, it's strange that updating it with the same fields leads to a 0 somewhere (probably one of the foreign keys).

You should debug this and there are two ways to go at it:

- Inspect your database using raw SQL. `manage.py dbshell` opens a SQL shell where you can do `SELECT * FROM my_app_tour WHERE id = 1`. Look at the particular row, maybe you can spot the issue.
- Try `test.save(update_fields=['status'])`. If that works, add more fields to update one by one, e.g. `test.save(update_fields=['status', 'tour_from']`, then `test.save(update_fields['status', 'tour_from', 'tour_to'])`... until the error is thrown again.

I suspect a database corruption, but there might be some other more serious issue in the way you create the objects. That would cause problems down the line.

Comment: The error happened when I add `creator` to `test.save`

Comment: Does it happen with any row (`pk`) or just this one. How did you create the object in the first place?

Comment: For any row this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Check your django_content_type table, look for 0's in the id column. Django logs database operations after each call, and it writes the ID of the content type.

I found that I had several entries with a 0 id. Updating these with unique numbers after the end of the sequence and restarting Django fixed this for me.

Honestly, I have no idea how it got that way. I'm using Django 2.2.